# How to solve "No Valid Data Send" message in magento product export

Tags: magento-1.7

When we export product detail in magento at time "No Valid Data Send" message display.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This error generate when in some data from database was not returned. i.e., if specific product has not selected category. In my Scenario, it was not returning category.

> Change in product.php
>
> /ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php
>
> (I will prefer to extend this file in your local pool)

```
protected function _updateDataWithCategoryColumns(&$dataRow, &$rowCategories, $productId)
{
    if (!isset($rowCategories[$productId])) {
        return false;
    }

    $categoryId = array_shift($rowCategories[$productId]);
    $dataRow[self::COL_ROOT_CATEGORY] = $this->_rootCategories[$categoryId];

    if (isset($this->_categories[$categoryId])) {
        $dataRow[self::COL_CATEGORY] = $this->_categories[$categoryId];
    }

    return true;
}
```

replace code of line

```
protected function _updateDataWithCategoryColumns(&$dataRow, &$rowCategories, $productId)
{
    if (!isset($rowCategories[$productId]) or empty($rowCategories[$productId])) {
        return false;
    }

    $categoryId = array_shift($rowCategories[$productId]);
    $dataRow[self::COL_ROOT_CATEGORY] = $this->_rootCategories[$categoryId];

    if (isset($this->_categories[$categoryId])) {
        $dataRow[self::COL_CATEGORY] = $this->_categories[$categoryId];
    }

    return true;
}
```